# How to access a webcam in Raspberry Pi Motion instead using the port

Tags: raspberry-pi, video-streaming, raspberry-pi2, raspberry-pi3, motion-detection

I am using a streaming of video, configured using this tutorial: https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-webcam-server

Can I configure the motion to access the webcam with a link like “ip:/cam1” where ip is like “146.106.91.100” instead using the port “:8081”?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the software you are, but after a quick search, it appears as though you can modify the following directive in your `motion.conf` configuration file:

```
############################################################
# HTTP Based Control
############################################################

# TCP/IP port for the http server to listen on (default: 0 = disabled)
webcontrol_port 8081
```

Change that port to `80`. That will prevent you from having to specify a port in the URL.

Please note that a Unix system will not allow anyone other than the superuser (`root`) to start services on port numbers < 1024, so you'd need to run the application as `root`, or with `sudo`. This can open up gaping security issues though, so I would not recommend taking this approach unless you're extremely confident that this is on a private, and/or secured network.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your Stream like this:

```
cvlc v4l2:// v4l2-dev=/dev/video0 --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:8080}' :demux=h264
```

or

```
cvlc v4l2:// v4l2-dev=/dev/video0 --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:8080/cam1}' :demux=h264
```

or

```
cvlc v4l2:// v4l2-dev=/dev/video0 --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=/cam1}' :demux=h264
```

in the last example you have to take care that port 80 is available on your system. It is normally used by the webserver.